# SQL - Insert into one column within table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, insert

so I just added a new column to a table and now i want to populate that column in the pre-existing rows. This my current query, but it keeps erroring, because its trying to insert into the first column of the table.

```
insert into Product_Database(UPC)
select u.UPC
from upc_temp u
    join upc_temp_gers g on u.PartNumber = g.PartNumber
    join Product_Database p on p.ITM_CD = g.ItemCode
where u.UPC is not null
```

and this is the error its returning

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ITM_CD'
```

Clearly i am not trying to insert into the 'ITM_CD' column. Just 'UPC'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the table definition of `Product_Database`? I'm certain there is a `not null` constraint  on the column `ITM_CD` and you are not providing any value for `ITM_CD`. Hence the row would have `NULL` as a value for `ITM_CD`, which the constraint prevents.

Answer (score 3):

> now i want to populate that column in the pre-existing rows.

After you add a new column to a table, you don't populate the new column for existing rows with an INSERT.

You do it with an UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the logic you want is:

```
update p 
    set UPC = u.UPC
    from upc_temp u join
         upc_temp_gers g
         on u.PartNumber = g.PartNumber join
         Product_Database p
         on p.ITM_CD = g.ItemCode
    where u.UPC is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UPDATE query for this.